# How to parse this html structure using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, django, beautifulsoup

I would like to parse this `TABLE` line by line and save to a csv file.
What I have done so far, return nothing in the csv file:

`Django`:

**data_scrapper** makes a request from Yahoo Finance.

```
def button_clicked(request):
    headers = []
    rows = []
    gen_table = data_scrapper(symbol)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(gen_table)
    table = soup.find_all('table')
    for table in soup.find_all('table'):
        headers.extend([header.text for header in table.find_all('th')])
    for row in soup.find_all('tr'):
        rows.extend([val.text for val in row.find_all('td')])

    response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename= "{}.csv"'.format(symbol)

    writer = csv.writer(response)
    writer.writerow(headers)
    writer.writerows(row for row in rows if row)

    return response
```

`html`:

```
<TABLE class="yfnc_tabledata1" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
  <TR>
    <TD>
      <TABLE width="100%" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" border="0">
        <TR class="yfnc_modtitle1" style="border-top:none;">
          <td colspan="2" style="border-top:2px solid #000;">
            <small>
              <span class="yfi-module-title">Period Ending</span>
            </small>
          </td>
          <th scope="col" style="border-top:2px solid #000;text-align:right; font-weight:bold">Dec 31, 2014</th>
          <th scope="col" style="border-top:2px solid #000;text-align:right; font-weight:bold">Dec 31, 2013</th>
          <th scope="col" style="border-top:2px solid #000;text-align:right; font-weight:bold">Dec 31, 2012</th>
        </TR>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2">
            <strong>
              Total Revenue
            </strong>
          </td>
          <td align="right">
            <strong>
              4,479,648&nbsp;&nbsp;
            </strong>
          </td>
          <td align="right">
            <strong>
              3,777,068&nbsp;&nbsp;
            </strong>
          </td>
          <td align="right">
            <strong>
              3,209,782&nbsp;&nbsp;
            </strong>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2">Cost of Revenue</td>
          <td align="right">3,160,470&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
          <td align="right">2,656,189&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
          <td align="right">2,284,485&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="5" style="height:0;padding:0; border-top:3px solid #333;">
            <span style="display:block; width:5px; height:1px;"></span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2">
            <strong>
              Gross Profit
            </strong>
          </td>
          <td align="right">
            <strong>
              1,319,178&nbsp;&nbsp;
            </strong>
          </td>
          <td align="right">
            <strong>
              1,120,879&nbsp;&nbsp;
            </strong>
          </td>
          <td align="right">
            <strong>
              925,297&nbsp;&nbsp;
            </strong>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="5" style="height:0;padding:0; ">
            <span style="display:block; width:5px; height:10px;"></span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <spacer type="block" height="1" width="1" />
          </td>
          <td class="yfnc_d" colspan="4">Operating Expenses</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="30" class="yfnc_tabledata1">
            <spacer type="block" width="30" height="1" />
          </td>
          <td>Research Development</td>
          <td align="right">148,458&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
          <td align="right">139,193&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
          <td align="right">127,361&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="30" class="yfnc_tabledata1">
            <spacer type="block" width="30" height="1" />
          </td>
          <td>Selling General and Administrative</td>
          <td align="right">456,030&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
          <td align="right">403,772&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
          <td align="right">319,511&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="30" class="yfnc_tabledata1">
            <spacer type="block" width="30" height="1" />
          </td>
          <td>Non Recurring</td>
          <td align="right">
            - &nbsp;
          </td>
          <td align="right">
            - &nbsp;
          </td>
          <td align="right">
            - &nbsp;
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="30" class="yfnc_tabledata1">
            <spacer type="block" width="30" height="1" />
          </td>
          <td>Others</td>
          <td align="right">
            - &nbsp;
          </td>
          <td align="right">
            - &nbsp;
          </td>
          <td align="right">
            - &nbsp;
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <spacer type="block" height="1" width="1" />
          </td>
          <td colspan="5" style="height:0; padding:0; " class="yfnc_d">
            <span style="display:block; width:5px; height:1px;"></span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="30" class="yfnc_tabledata1">
            <spacer type="block" width="30" height="1" />
          </td>
          <td>Total Operating Expenses</td>
          <td align="right">
            - &nbsp;
          </td>
          <td align="right">
            - &nbsp;
          </td>
          <td align="right">
            - &nbsp;
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="5" style="height:0;padding:0; ">
            <span style="display:block; width:5px; height:10px;"></span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="5" style="height:0;padding:0; border-top:3px solid #333;">
            <span style="display:block; width:5px; height:1px;"></span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2">
            <strong>
              Operating Income or Loss
            </strong>
          </td>
          <td align="right">
            <strong>
              714,690&nbsp;&nbsp;
            </strong>
          </td>
          <td align="right">
            <strong>
              577,914&nbsp;&nbsp;
            </strong>
          </td>
          <td align="right">
            <strong>
              478,425&nbsp;&nbsp;
            </strong>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="5" style="height:0;padding:0; ">
            <span style="display:block; width:5px; height:10px;"></span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <spacer type="block" height="1" width="1" />
          </td>
          <td class="yfnc_d" colspan="4">Income from Continuing Operations</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="30" class="yfnc_tabledata1">
            <spacer type="block" width="30" height="1" />
          </td>
          <td>Total Other Income/Expenses Net</td>
          <td align="right">(10)</td>
          <td align="right">5,139&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
          <td align="right">7,529&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="30" class="yfnc_tabledata1">
            <spacer type="block" width="30" height="1" />
          </td>
          <td>Earnings Before Interest And Taxes</td>
          <td align="right">710,556&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
          <td align="right">580,639&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
          <td align="right">485,775&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="30" class="yfnc_tabledata1">
            <spacer type="block" width="30" height="1" />
          </td>
          <td>Interest Expense</td>
          <td align="right">11,239&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
          <td align="right">6,210&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
          <td align="right">5,932&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="30" class="yfnc_tabledata1">
            <spacer type="block" width="30" height="1" />
          </td>
          <td>Income Before Tax</td>
          <td align="right">699,317&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
          <td align="right">574,429&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
          <td align="right">479,843&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="30" class="yfnc_tabledata1">
            <spacer type="block" width="30" height="1" />
          </td>
          <td>Income Tax Expense</td>
          <td align="right">245,288&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
          <td align="right">193,360&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
          <td align="right">167,533&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="30" class="yfnc_tabledata1">
            <spacer type="block" width="30" height="1" />
          </td>
          <td>Minority Interest</td>
          <td align="right">
            - &nbsp;
          </td>
          <td align="right">
            - &nbsp;
          </td>
          <td align="right">
            - &nbsp;
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <spacer type="block" height="1" width="1" />
          </td>
          <td colspan="5" style="height:0; padding:0; " class="yfnc_d">
            <span style="display:block; width:5px; height:1px;"></span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="30" class="yfnc_tabledata1">
            <spacer type="block" width="30" height="1" />
          </td>
          <td>Net Income From Continuing Ops</td>
          <td align="right">454,029&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
          <td align="right">381,069&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
          <td align="right">312,310&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="5" style="height:0;padding:0; ">
            <span style="display:block; width:5px; height:10px;"></span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <spacer type="block" height="1" width="1" />
          </td>
          <td class="yfnc_d" colspan="4">Non-recurring Events</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="30" class="yfnc_tabledata1">
            <spacer type="block" width="30" height="1" />
          </td>
          <td>Discontinued Operations</td>
          <td align="right">
            - &nbsp;
          </td>
          <td align="right">(3,777)</td>
          <td align="right">
            - &nbsp;
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="30" class="yfnc_tabledata1">
            <spacer type="block" width="30" height="1" />
          </td>
          <td>Extraordinary Items</td>
          <td align="right">
            - &nbsp;
          </td>
          <td align="right">
            - &nbsp;
          </td>
          <td align="right">
            - &nbsp;
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="30" class="yfnc_tabledata1">
            <spacer type="block" width="30" height="1" />
          </td>
          <td>Effect Of Accounting Changes</td>
          <td align="right">
            - &nbsp;
          </td>
          <td align="right">
            - &nbsp;
          </td>
          <td align="right">
            - &nbsp;
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="30" class="yfnc_tabledata1">
            <spacer type="block" width="30" height="1" />
          </td>
          <td>Other Items</td>
          <td align="right">
            - &nbsp;
          </td>
          <td align="right">
            - &nbsp;
          </td>
          <td align="right">
            - &nbsp;
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="5" style="height:0;padding:0; ">
            <span style="display:block; width:5px; height:10px;"></span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="5" style="height:0;padding:0; border-top:3px solid #333;">
            <span style="display:block; width:5px; height:1px;"></span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2">
            <strong>
              Net Income
            </strong>
          </td>
          <td align="right">
            <strong>
              454,029&nbsp;&nbsp;
            </strong>
          </td>
          <td align="right">
            <strong>
              377,292&nbsp;&nbsp;
            </strong>
          </td>
          <td align="right">
            <strong>
              312,310&nbsp;&nbsp;
            </strong>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2">Preferred Stock And Other Adjustments</td>
          <td align="right">
            - &nbsp;
          </td>
          <td align="right">
            - &nbsp;
          </td>
          <td align="right">
            - &nbsp;
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="5" style="height:0;padding:0; border-top:3px solid #333;">
            <span style="display:block; width:5px; height:1px;"></span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2">
            <strong>
              Net Income Applicable To Common Shares
            </strong>
          </td>
          <td align="right">
            <strong>
              454,029&nbsp;&nbsp;
            </strong>
          </td>
          <td align="right">
            <strong>
              377,292&nbsp;&nbsp;
            </strong>
          </td>
          <td align="right">
            <strong>
              312,310&nbsp;&nbsp;
            </strong>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </TABLE>
    </TD>
  </TR>
</TABLE>
```

Comment: What do you expect the header of the CSV file to look like?

Comment: @cameron-f: period ending date, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some code that makes a csv that looks like the table.  The csvs I usually work with have a row as a complete record.  So all the values in column one would be the csv header.  Just something to think about, it might be helpful

Python 3.4

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import csv

def button_clicked(request, filename):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(request)
    table = soup.find('table').find('table') 
    t_rows = table.find_all('tr')

    with open(filename, 'w') as csvfile:
        spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',',
                                quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)

        for t_row in t_rows:
            rec_as_str = t_row.getText()
            rec_as_str = rec_as_str.strip()
            rec_as_str = rec_as_str.replace('\xa0', '')
            rec_as_str = re.sub('\\n?\s*(\\n)+\s*', '|', rec_as_str)
            if len(rec_as_str) > 0:
                a_list = rec_as_str.split("|")
                spamwriter.writerow(a_list)
```

Creates a file that looks like:

```
Period Ending,"Dec 31, 2014","Dec 31, 2013","Dec 31, 2012"
Total Revenue,"4,479,648","3,777,068","3,209,782"
Cost of Revenue,"3,160,470","2,656,189","2,284,485"
Gross Profit,"1,319,178","1,120,879","925,297"
Operating Expenses
Research Development,"148,458","139,193","127,361"
Selling General and Administrative,"456,030","403,772","319,511"
Non Recurring,-,-,-
Others,-,-,-
Total Operating Expenses,-,-,-
Operating Income or Loss,"714,690","577,914","478,425"
Income from Continuing Operations
Total Other Income/Expenses Net,(10),"5,139","7,529"
Earnings Before Interest And Taxes,"710,556","580,639","485,775"
Interest Expense,"11,239","6,210","5,932"
Income Before Tax,"699,317","574,429","479,843"
Income Tax Expense,"245,288","193,360","167,533"
Minority Interest,-,-,-
Net Income From Continuing Ops,"454,029","381,069","312,310"
Non-recurring Events
Discontinued Operations,-,"(3,777)",-
Extraordinary Items,-,-,-
Effect Of Accounting Changes,-,-,-
Other Items,-,-,-
Net Income,"454,029","377,292","312,310"
Preferred Stock And Other Adjustments,-,-,-
Net Income Applicable To Common Shares,"454,029","377,292","312,310"
```

Comment: @Bun What are you looking for?